# Showing undefine on my bar chart

Tags: php, charts

Good day. I was having this problem which I don't know how to solve. To start with, here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$.ajax({
    url: "test.php",
    method: "GET",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var shclYear = [];
        var enrls = [];

        for(var i in data) {
            shclYear.push(data[i].schoolyear);
            enrls.push(data[i].enrollees);
        }

        var chartData = {
            labels: shclYear,
            datasets : [
                {
                    label : "School Year",
                    data : enrls
                }
            ]
        };

        var ctx = $('#myCanvas');

        var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: chartData

        });
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
}); });
```

The test.php generate a same data which in json_encode format:

`[{"schoolyear":"2010","enrollees":"100"},{"schoolyear":"2011","enrollees":"150"},{"schoolyear":"2012","enrollees":"300"},{"schoolyear":"2013","enrollees":"250"}]`

I am wondering, my in my html, it is showing undefined, undefined. Will anybody please explain why. Thank you very much.

by the way, here's my php code:`    include('dbFunction.php');

```
$dbOperation = new dbFunctions();
$qryData = $dbOperation->selectQry('Select schoolyear, enrollees From testData');

$data = array();

//for ($x=0; $row=$qryData->fetch(); $x++) {
foreach ($qryData as $row) {
    # code...
//}
    $data[] = array_unique($row);

    //echo $data .'<br>';
}

echo json_encode($data);`
```

Comment: post your test.php file

Comment: Sorry, i have updated my post with my php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` is an array `[]`, not an object `{}`

therefore, shouldn't use `for ( .. in ..)`

instead, use traditional for loop...

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  shclYear.push(data[i].schoolyear);
  enrls.push(data[i].enrollees);
}
```

or for each...

```
data.forEach(function (row) {
  shclYear.push(row.schoolyear);
  enrls.push(row.enrollees);
});
```

also, probably want to set the type to json on the ajax call...

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.php",
  method: "GET",
  dataType: "json",
  ...
```